# php result it's not > 0 if i have 3 variables

Tags: java, php

It's probably very easy question, but i'm workin on login form. For now it works fine - if username and password are correct you successfully login. But now i made one more variable $breed and i need php code that successfully login if also breed is correct. This code does not work (it shows) if the third variable ($breed) is also included:

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];
$breed = $_POST["breed"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from tabela where username like '$user_name' and password like '$password' and breed like '$breed';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "log";
}
else {
echo "login not success";
}

?>
```

There could be also sth wrong with java code in android, but i doubt it cuz it works perfectly if there is only username and password:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        if(result.contentEquals("log")) {

            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Boxer.class));

        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Wrong Username or Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



    }
```

Comment: show us the login form

Comment: form is made in android studio, i added some code

Comment: What does it show? This is open to SQL injections, you shouldn't use `like` for exact comparisons, and don't store plain text passwords.

Comment: try this query `select * from tabela where username = '$user_name' and password= '$password' and breed = '$breed';`

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222549/php-mysql-check-if-username-and-password-are-in-the-database

Comment: Beware of user [“Little Bobby Tables”](https://xkcd.com/327/)  - (obligatory xkcd reference)

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally use a count function to retrieve the number of users with the given combination

```
select count(*) as count from LOGIN_TABLE where USERNAME='your_input' and PASSWORD='your_input' and BREED='your_input';
```

This type of query help reducing possible threats to your code. You should never use LIKE in matching username and passwords, as they are supposed to be an exact match.